# issue with cacluation value ROW(row index )

Tags: excel

i have excel with some forumal like

```
=B9*(1-$B$4/(1+(ROW(B9)-ROW($B$8))*$B$5))
```

i can not get what does ROW(B9) - ROW($B$8) means also my calculation differs from excel outut due to calculation of ROW(B9)

Please exlain what does it mean

Comment: Have you tried looking up the `ROW()` function? Your question isn't clear, especially "also my calculation differs from excel outut." Assuming you mean "output," what output would that be?

Comment: ROW returns the row of the range in it, so `ROW(B9)` returns 9 and `ROW($B$8)` returns 8, so 9 - 8 = 1

Answer (score 3):

Row returns the row (as a number) of the cell in reference, or itself.

Working in cell D2:
`=row()` --> 2, but copy D2 to D3 and it gives 3 because now in row 3
`=row(B9)` --> 9, but copy D2 to D3 and it gives 10 because reference cell moved 1 row down
`=row($B$8)` --> 8, regardless of what row you are in. Copy from D2 to D8 and still gives 8 due to absolute reference (`$`)